shap beeswarm plot with setfit huggingface
I want to show the beeswarm plot in SHAP with huggingface SetFit for few shot learning. The issue that I am facing is beeswarm expects the shap values to be a 2D matrix of fixed shape but my shape is (10,None,2).
Where None is the dimension of number of tokens in each sentence. the task is of binary classification.
I am training the model like this:
trainer = SetFitTrainer(
        model=model,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=test_dataset,
        loss_class=CosineSimilarityLoss,
        num_iterations=20,
        use_amp=True,
        num_epochs=3,
        batch_size=8,
        column_mapping={"text": "text", "label": "label"}
    )

I think the issue is that I am passing it the raw text, but if I tokenized it and pass, I get this error:
An error occurred: The following columns are missing from the column mapping: {'label', 'text'}. Please provide a mapping for all required columns.

If I do:
shap.plots.beeswarm(shap_values, max_display=20)

I get this error:
ValueError: The beeswarm plot does not support plotting explanations with instances that have more than one dimension!

Can anyone please help me with applying tokenizer on the setfit model, or better to get beeswarm plot from setfit trained model. Thanks!
